# How to change the username displayed in SSH cmd line

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

When I login to an Ubuntu server the username is displayed as `user@abc-123:~#` how do I change this? eg. I want `user@servername:~#`.

Comment: How do the two prompts differ? Is `abc-123` not a `servername`? From now, it is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to choose a custom name, not just the server name but I would like to know how to have it as the server name too

Comment: You might find something here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81133/change-terminal-prompt-ubuntu

Comment: In order to give a specific response please include the output of `echo $SHELL` in your question, since the answer might depend on the shell in use.

Comment: SSH does not control the command line prompt. You might want to edit the subject to indicate which shell you are using (presumably "bash")

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the bash(1) (perhaps others) shell then you will need to manipulate the $PS1 environment variable. This is normaly achieved by putting the appropriate commands in a suitable shell initialisation file.